# Pyevolve with multi processing using more RAM with each GA generation

Tags: python-multiprocessing, pyevolve

I am using pyevolve to run a GA using multi processing. The code runs fine but uses more memory with every new generation of GA. The code is creating new jobs for each generation while the previous ones are idle while reserving RAM.It finally crashes after around 10 generations.  How do I correct this?[Ram Usage][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/knCC0.jpg

```
def main_run():

    flowargs, rhoargs, zindex=get_params()
    genome = G1DList.G1DList(18)
    genome.initializator.set(myGA.myInitializator)
    genome.crossover.set(myGA.mycrossover)
    genome.mutator.set(pl.Mutators.G1DListMutatorSwap)
    genome.setParams(z=zindex,f=flowargs,r=rhoargs)
    genome.evaluator.set(get_rho)
    ga = GSimpleGA.GSimpleGA(genome)
    ga.minimax = Consts.minimaxType["minimize"]
    ga.setGenerations(100)
    ga.selector.set(Selectors.GRouletteWheel)
    ga.setInteractiveMode(False)
    ga.setMultiProcessing(True)
    ga.evolve(freq_stats=1)
    best = ga.bestIndividual()
    print(best)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this problem a while back, and after much research I found the answer,

You have to
modify the `GPopulation.py` in the library source code,

--Add the following two commands:

```
proc_pool.close()
proc_pool.join()
```

--before the last line of the `function evaluate(self, **args)`

--Rebuild and re-install the libraries.
*i.e.
C:\Pevolve Source code\Pyevolve-0.6rc1\pyevolve\GPopulation (mine was here)*

Edit with IDLE

--Add `proc_pool.close()` & `proc_pool.join()` just before `self.clearFlags()`

### --Save

Open Command Prompt

1. Go to C:\Pevolve Source code\Pyevolve-0.6rc1
2. setup.py build
3. setup.py install